# Error when Import pptx "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."

Tags: python, pip, lxml, conda, python-pptx

I have a very similar issue to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210888/importerror-with-python-pptx) however the solution is not fixing my issue. I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pptx.api import Presentation  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .package import Package
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\package.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .opc.package import OpcPackage
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .oxml import CT_Relationships, serialize_part_xml
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\oxml.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

On my initial install of python-pptx I used:

```
pip install python-pptx
```

which is not working as the OP said was working for him in his post.  I have used pip uninstall and reinstalled, and get the same error. I also tried to just install again and get:

```
Looking in indexes: website name was here
Requirement already satisfied: python-pptx in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.6.18)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.1.0 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-pptx) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=3.3.2 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-pptx) (6.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: XlsxWriter>=0.5.7 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-pptx) (1.1.2)
```

conda install lxml will update

```
ca-certificates:        2018.03.07-0           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main --> 2019.11.27-0           /
    certifi:                2018.11.29-py37_0      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main --> 2019.11.28-py37_0      /
    conda:                  4.5.12-py37_0          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main --> 4.7.12-py37_0          /
    libxml2:                2.9.8-hadb2253_1       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main --> 2.9.9-h464c3ec_0       /
    libxslt:                1.1.32-hf6f1972_0      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main --> 1.1.33-h579f668_0      /
    lxml:                   4.2.5-py37hef2cd61_0   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main --> 4.4.2-py37h1350720_0   /
    openssl:                1.1.1a-he774522_0      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main --> 1.1.1d-he774522_3      /
    qt:                     5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main [vc14] --> 5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0   /
    vc:                     14.1-h0510ff6_4        https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main --> 14.1-h0510ff6_4        /
    vs2015_runtime:         14.15.26706-h3a45250_0 https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main --> 14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_0 /
```

but I still get an error.
When I run pip install lxml  I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.4.2)
```

So I'm completely lost right now about what to do to get this to work.  Any help is much appreciated! TIA!

UPDATE:  I uninstalled `python-pptx` and then `lxml` and then just did `pip install python-pptx` and I think it may be working.

Answer (score -2):

upgrade lxml to the latest version via pip install --upgrade lxml worked for me.

Comment: This question was asked almost a year ago and the op found a solution. And, as he stated in his question, he did update lxml (via conda) and it didn't work.